# Can't figure out my syntax error with JavaScript credit card validation

Tags: javascript, validation, debugging

I'm learning JavaScript and and am trying to do credit card validation in a form. I'm getting a syntax error on line 10 of the code below and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I also noticed when I add the last curly brace in Text Wrangler it says I have an unmatched curly brace but if I go through and count them they seem to match up so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateCard() {
if (document.forms[0].cardName.value == "American Express") {
    var cardProtocol = new RegExp("^3[47][0-9]{13}$");
    if (cardProtocol.test(document.forms[0].cardNumber.value))
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Valid credit card number";
    else
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Invalid credit card number";
    } 
else if (document.forms[0].cardName.value == "Diners Club" {
    var cardProtocol = new RegExp ("^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}$");
    if (cardProtocol.test(document.forms[0].cardNumber.value))
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Valid credit card number";
    else
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Invalid credit card number";
    }
else if (document.forms[0].cardName.value == "Discover" {
    var cardProtocol = new RegExp ("^6(?:011|5[0-9]{12}$");
    if (cardProtocol.test(document.forms[0].cardNumber.value))
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Valid credit card number";
    else
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Invalid credit card number";
    }
else if (document.forms[0].cardName.value == "JCB" {
    var cardProtocol = new RegExp ("^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}$");
    if (cardProtocol.test(document.forms[0].cardNumber.value))
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Valid credit card number";
    else
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Invalid credit card number";
    }
else if (document.forms[0].cardName.value == "Mastercard" {
    var cardProtocol = new RegExp ("^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$");
    if (cardProtocol.test(document.forms[0].cardNumber.value))
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Valid credit card number";
    else
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Invalid credit card number";
    }
else if (document.forms[0].cardName.value == "Visa" {
    var cardProtocol = new RegExp ("^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$");
    if (cardProtocol.test(document.forms[0].cardNumber.value))
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Valid credit card number";
    else
        document.forms[0].ccResult.value = "Invalid credit card number";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You're missing two `}` at the end of your script??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions of your `if` don't have a closing `)`, your `else` don't have opening `{` and so much more. You can use a tool like [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) to check your syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the resource, the closing ) solved the problem.